# Does metabase.com support SQL PIVOT and UN-PIVOT?

Tags: pivot, pivot-table, unpivot, metabase

I am trying to do PIVOT in SQL in metabase.com. Facing multiple errors which executing. Any one tried SQL PIVOT in METABASE.

If anyone faced similar issue or any solution for the same

Comment: There are a lot of examples of how to write "pivot" in MySQL's limited SQL.  See the tag `[pivot-table]`

Comment: Is this a question for metabase as the question's text suggests or is this a question for the underlying database as the tagging suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

You have to save your query as a question, then you go to the GUI editor and use your saved question as data to the analysis.

And in the end, after run the query, you will be able to use the pivot table feature clicking in "display".